# Bash scripting: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, for-loop, scripting

I am new to bash scripting and I have to create this script that takes 3 directories as arguments and copies in the third one all the files in the first one that are NOT in the second one.

I did it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d $1 && -d $2 && -d $3 ]; then
    for FILE in [ ls $1 ]; do
        if ! [ find $2 -name $FILE ]; then
            cp $FILE $3
    done
else echo "Error: one or more directories are not present"
fi
```

The error I get when I try to execute it is: "line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done' "
I don't really know how to make it work! 
Also even if I'm using #!/bin/bash I still have to explicitly call bash when trying to execute, otherwise it says that executing is not permitted, anybody knows why?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: By the way, it will be good if you mention whether your input directories contain subdirectories?

Comment: Right! No they don't contain any subdirectory!

Answer (score 3):

Couple of suggestions :

1. No harm double quoting variables

   ```
   cp "$FILE" "$3" # prevents wordsplitting, helps you filenames with spaces
   ```
2. `for` statement fails for the fundamental reason -bad syntax- it should've been:

   ```
   for FILE in ls "$1";
   ```
3. But then, never parse `ls` output. Check [[ this ]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

   ```
    for FILE in ls "$1"; #drastic
   ```
4. Instead of the `for-loop` in step2 use a `find-while-read` combination:

   ```
   find "$1" -type f -print0 | while read -rd'' filename #-type f for files
   do
   #something with $filename
   done
   ```
5. Use lowercase variable names for your script as uppercase variables are reserved for the system. Check [[this]](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).
6. Use tools like [[ shellcheck ]](http://shellcheck.net) to improve script quality.

**Edit**

Since you have mentioned the input directories contain only files, my alternative approach would be

```
[[ -d "$1" && -d "$2" && -d "$3" ]] && for filename in "$1"/*
do
    [ ! -e "$2/${filename##*/}" ] && cp "$filename" "$3"
done
```

If you are baffled by `${filename##*/}` check [[ shell parameter expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

---

<sup>**Sidenote**: In linux, although discouraged it not uncommon to have non-standard filenames like `file name`.

**Courtesy**: [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) & [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for their comments that greatly improved this answer :)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I will try and understand them because I have started studying bash scripting literally yesterday and many things that you wrote are still kind of hard to understand for me, but I'll try and implement your suggestions

Comment: @BattiestFawn66 Appreciate the great attitude :)

Comment: Right, I'll try to figure it out!

Comment: @BattiestFawn66 : See the complete solution in the edit part

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer; one more suggestion: while lowercase variable names certainly work, the variable names to avoid are those that are _all_-uppercase (e.g., `FILE`), so having at least _one_ lowercase character is sufficient, so that camel-casing, for instance, is fine (e.g., `userName`).

Comment: (Also, unlike what I claimed in an earlier comment, you were actually fully justified in calling filenames with embedded spaces non-standard (or at least non-portable), because the set of portable filename characters does indeed not include spaces - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_278, even though it's reasonable to expect them on pretty much any platform these days.)

Comment: @mklement0 : In fact I was searching for the above link for a counter argument.. ;) Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Your script:

```
if ...; then
  for ...; do
    if ...; then
      ...
  done
else
  ...
fi
```

Fixed structure:

```
if ...; then
  for ...; do
    if ...; then
      ...
    fi       # <-- missing
  done
else
  ...
fi
```

If you want the script executable, then make it so:

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
```

Notice that you also have other problems in you script. It is better written as

```
dir1="$1"
dir2="$2"
dir3="$3"

for f in "$dir1"/*; do
  if [ ! -f "$dir2/$(basename "$f")" ]; then
    cp "$f" "$dir3"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Yeah I has thought about it but still doesn't work :(

Comment: @BattiestFawn66 "does not work"?  Please update the question with you modified script.

Comment: Why keep on adding variables `dir1,dir2,dir3`? Also `basename` and `if` clause are completely unnecessary here. Most bash shells do support shell parameter expansion. You can get the basename using `${f##*/}`. Why have subprocess then?

Comment: @mona_sax In general, I tend to put the values of any positional variables in variables with *descriptive names*.  I also used `basename` rather than a variable substitution for portability. There is nothing wrong with using a variable substitution though.

Comment: If you're really worried about `${foo##bar}` (introduced in bash 4.3-beta) being not very portable, you could use `${foo/pattern/replacement}` style which was introduced way back in bash 2.0(released late 1996). In your case it would be `${f/*\/}`.

Comment: @mona_sax `${foo##*/}` is completely portable (specified by POSIX, not a bash extension). The problem with it, though, is that it can give the wrong result if your directory name ends with a `/`; with `foo=/some/dir/`, compare `${foo##*/}` with `$(basename "$foo")`.

Answer (score 1):

this is not totally correct:

```
for FILE in $(ls $1); do 
    < whatever you do here >
done
```

There is a big problem with that loop if in that folder there is a filename like this: **'I am a filename with spaces.txt'**.
Instead of that loop try this:

```
for FILE in "$1"/*; do
    echo "$FILE"
done
```

Also you have to close every **if** statement with **fi**.

Another thing, if you are using BASH ( **#!/usr/bin/env bash** ), it is highly recommended to use double brackets in your test conditions:

```
if [[ test ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

For example:

```
$ a='foo bar'
$ if [[ $a == 'foo bar' ]]; then
> echo "it's ok"
> fi
it's ok
```

However, this:

```
$ if [ $a == 'foo bar' ]; then
> echo "it's ok"; 
> fi
bash: [: too many arguments
```

Comment: Good point about filenames with embedded spaces, but for the same reason you should use `"$1"/*` rather than `$1/*`; also, avoiding all-uppercase variable names is recommended.

Comment: @mklement0 you're right. Without quotes on $1 my solution fails if $1 contains spaces. Good point for you!. I change it now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

You've forgot `fi` after the innermost `if`.

Additionally, neither square brackets nor `find` do work this way. This one does what your script (as it is now) is intended to on my PC:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -d "$1" && -d "$2" && -d "$3" ]] ; then
    ls -1 "$1" | while read FILE ; do
        ls "$2/$FILE" >/dev/null 2>&1 || cp "$1/$FILE" "$3"
    done
else echo "Error: one or more directories are not present"
fi
```

Note that after a single run, when $2 and $3 refer to different directories, those files are still not present in $2, so next time you run the script they will be copied once more despite they already are present in $3.

Comment: I had thought about it and I put "fi" right before "done" but it gives me the exact same error! Did I have to put "fi" somewhere else?

Comment: Either put it on a new line right above `done`, or you can place them in the same line but separate them with semicolon: `fi ; done`.

Comment: BTW, `for FILE in [ ls $1 ]` is simply wrong; either use backticks or `$()` for command expansion: `for FILE in $(ls $1)`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Unfortunately it is still not working, I think the problem might be somewhere else :/

Comment: @sjsam, can we leave that aside for now? This might be not the best way to obtain the list of files, but that definitely is not the most serious problem here. :)

Comment: Downvote: Bad practices should not be tolerated. Never parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: Okay. Shall we hereby declare this comment thread the official place for condemning `ls` output parsing?